# Two time-varying coefficients in Kalman filter with DLM package

Tags: r, kalman-filter, dlm

I am trying to estimate a model that has two time varying coefficients in R using the "DLM" package.

My measurement equation would be = Yt = F1t*x1t + F2t*x2t + v

The state equations are:

F1t = F1t-1 + w1

F2t = F2t-1 + w2

In DLM notation, given that the two coefficients are time-varying, FF = (0,0) and JFF = (1,1) (I think).

The code I use to estimate is the following:

```
myBuild = function(x){
  r1 = c(exp(x[2]),0);
  r2 = c(0,exp(x[3]));
  W = rbind(r1,r2);
  modBuild = dlm(m0 = c(0,0), C0 = 0.0001*diag(2),
                 FF = matrix(c(0,0),nrow=1,ncol=2),
                 V=exp(x[1]), GG = diag(2), W=W,
                 JFF = matrix(c(1,1),nrow=1,ncol=2), X = X.vars);
  return(modBuild);
}

fitTemp = dlmMLE(y, parm = rep(0, 3), build = myBuild,
                 hessian = TRUE, control = list(maxit = 1000));
myModel = dlm(m0 = c(0,0), C0 = 0.0001*diag(2),
              FF = matrix(c(0,0),nrow=1,ncol=2),
              V=exp(fitTemp$par[1]), GG = diag(2), 

W=exp(fitTemp$par[-1])*diag(2),
                  JFF = matrix(c(1,1),nrow=1,ncol=2), X = X.vars);
```

However when I conduct this estimation, the variances of the two state variables become the same and the filtering two equal values for all the series. What am I doing wrong so that DLM is not understanding I need two time varying state variables?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, to whoever this concerns in the future. The issue was the JFF matrix, its integers have to correspond to the columns of matrix X. So for a 2 variable state estimation, FF = c(0,0) and JFF = c(1,2).